# Rspec: how to test Rails' url_for helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using RSpec, how do I test url_for helper method to make sure to it goes to the correct controller and action with a particular format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do the following --

Add this to spec_helper.rb:

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers  # url_for
end
```

Then:

```
describe "Article routing" do
  it "routes to #index.atom" do
    get('/articles.atom').
      should route_to('articles#index', format: 'atom')

    url_for(:controller => 'articles', :format => :atom, :only_path => true).
      should == '/articles/index.atom'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test that named routes are routed to the correct place. Routing specs live in `spec/routing`,so the following specs would be added to `spec/routing/widget_routes_spec.rb`

```
describe "routes to the widgets controller" do
  it "routes a named route" do
    expect(:get => new_widget_path).
      to route_to(:controller => "widgets", :action => "new")
  end
end
```

There are a lot of other options for testing routes described in the [routing specs documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs).